# Is there a difference between uniform distributed and equidistributed?

Tags: probability, random-variables

As the Title says, is there a difference between uniform distributed and equidistributed?

Aspecially in the context of random variables?

I did not find anything online, neither did my professor ever mention it.
So is it the same?

Comment: I think rv's $X,Y$ are "equidistributed" (or identically distributed) if they have equal distributions (so no connection with uniform distribution). I am not sure though.

Comment: thats the identical in i.i.d. yes.
But we had a example where he stated X to be equidistributed with p = 1/|X|.
and thats what I thought is uniform distributed